# Keychain not firing on iOS

Tags: ios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

The keychain won't autofill my login form on iOS.

In xCode I set Keychain Sharing to on and I have checkmarks next to both steps: Add the Keychain Sharing entitlement to your entitlements file & Add the Keychain Sharing feature to your App ID.

```
              <TextField
                class="input"
                hint="Email"
                keyboardType="email"
                autocorrect="false"
                autocapitalizationType="none"
                v-model="user.email"
                returnKeyType="next"
                @returnPress="focusPassword"
                fontSize="18"
              />
              <StackLayout class="hr-light"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout class="input-field" marginBottom="15">
              <TextField
                ref="password"
                class="input"
                hint="Password"
                secure="true"
                v-model="user.password"
                :returnKeyType="isLoggingIn ? 'done' : 'next'"
                fontSize="18"
              />
              <StackLayout class="hr-light"/>
            </StackLayout>
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is that I need to set the  `textContentType` to .username & .password but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to set the `textContentType` on the nativeView,

Add `loaded` event to TextField

```
      <TextField
            class="input"
            hint="Email"
            keyboardType="email"
            autocorrect="false"
            autocapitalizationType="none"
            v-model="user.email"
            returnKeyType="next"
            @loaded="onLoaded"
            @returnPress="focusPassword"
            fontSize="18"
          />
```

Update `textContentType` on nativeView

```
onLoaded: function(args) {
  const textField = args.object;
  if (textField.ios) {
     textField.ios.textContentType = UITextContentTypeEmailAddress;
  }
}
```

`textContentType` should be one of the values from [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype?language=objc).

Also make sure you run this code only on iOS 11 or later. If you are supporting iOS 10, this line of code might throw an exception. You will have to check for platform version in the `if` condition if you are supporting iOS 10.

Comment: To check iOS version you could use `iosUtils.MajorVersion` from `import { ios as iosUtils } from "tns-core-modules/utils/utils"`

Comment: Yes, you could use that to check the version.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks but keychain still isn't prompting me. I'm logging textField.ios.textContentType after I set it to username and password and it logs `username` and `password` as I would expect but keychain is still unresponsive. I'm testing on a physical device running iOS 12 with the keychain enabled so I shouldn't be hitting any issue with simulator or old OS. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you already signed up and let the application store the new email address and password? Can you share the sample project?

Comment: @Manoj Yes, I've signed up with the same username and pass several times. Keychain and autofill are enabled on the device. Unfortunately I can't share the whole project as it's my company's private repo. Should iOS be prompting me to add to keychain or does it do that automatically? Sorry, I'm an Android user.

Comment: To be precise, I didn't ask for whole project. I asked for a sample one only with enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry, misread that. It actually was my device. I tested on another one today and it worked fine. Thank you very much for all your help!